# How can I get email notifications for my investigations only?

Tags: teamcity

I want to receive email notifications whenever I am assigned new investigations. I've found under `My Settings & Tools > Notification Rules` there's an `Email Notifier` section, but I can only find a checkbox for `Investigation is updated`. This spams me with everyone's investigations, whereas I only want to see those assigned to me.

[image: teamcity notification rules]

Is there some way I can set up a notification rule for only my assigned investigations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the "Notification rules" tab, you can see Inherited rules :

There is a default Rule, inherited from "All Users" which contains all TeamCity users, which is, by default :

**Watching**: `System wide events`

**Send Notification when**: `Investigation assigned to me`

So, what you are looking for is the default behaviour on TeamCity 9 and TeamCity 10.